# Return type of statement

Tags: mysql

What is the return datatype of this statement :

```
INSERT INTO sample_table
VALUES ( 
    #{id},          
    #{Name},             
    ...     
) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE     
    column_id   = VALUES(column_id),                                
    column_name     = VALUES(column_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rows_affected is set
Errors could occur

But there is no "datatype" being returned.  `SELECTs` return resultsets; writes do not.